# Send Email through Javascript/HTML using user client

Tags: javascript, html, email

I know this question has been somewhat answered already in that using client-side scripting does not send emails, but please bear with me. I would like to have a 'send email' form on my website. The thing is that the website will be used by a handful of people who do have an email client installed. So I *DO* want to use their installed client, but I *don't* want the client to pop up. Is it possible to have the client do the work and send the email in the background, or must it popup every time?

If it is not possible, can anyone direct me to which server-side scripting language would be the most efficient at emailing a form? And if there are any relevant online tutorials on the matter?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Not possible.  Thankfully, JavaScript can't do a whole lot on a host system from within a web browser without user interaction.  As for the server-side language, any will have this functionality.

Comment: Thank you David. Would it then be a bad idea to go with PHP? It seems to have a lot of information and tutorials about it online

Comment: Yazan, PHP as you say has a lot of documentation and has an easy mail implementation. w3schools has a basic but useful tutorial on how to implement http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp